# Configuring ROS environment for Fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Can someone tell me how to configure the environment for Fuerte so that I can get my custom packages to run as before?

I am looking for something similar to this:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

Thanks
Cheers

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32661/configuring-ros-environment-for-fuerte/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use rosinstall. Suppose you want to put your local packages into ~/ros-fuerte/workspace and create an overlay in ~/ros-fuerte:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install rosinstall

mkdir -p ~/ros-fuerte/workspace
rosinstall ~/ros-fuerte /opt/ros/fuerte ~/ros-fuerte/workspace
```

This creates a setup.bash and friends in ~/ros-fuerte. Source it and your environment should be set.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-26**:
Good approach, and it works similarly for Electric workspaces. I like the new `rosws` script, which is packaged with `rosinstall`. http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws.html

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-04-26**:
Yes. rosws is probably the better choice.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-04-26**:
@Lorenz Thank you very much!